# How to get output result together with input table in Pig Latin?

Tags: input, output, apache-pig

I have the following input data table:

```
Product Price  Country
A       5       Italy
B       4       USA
C       12      France
A       5       Italy
B       7       Russia
```

I'm doing summarize operation by 2 IDs (product and country). The code is following:

```
t3 = LOAD '/home/Desktop/3_table.data' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (product:chararray, price:int, country:chararray);

group_pr = GROUP t3 BY (product, country);

price_1 = FOREACH group_pr GENERATE CONCAT(group.product, group.country), SUM(t3.price);

STORE price_1 INTO 'sum_by_product_country' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

The output is:

```
AItaly  10
BUSA    4
BRussia 7
CFrance 12
```

The problem is, that I have to get the full table that contains as input data and output all together, so expecting output should be something like this:

```
A       5       Italy           AItaly      10
B       4       USA             BUSA        4
C       12      France          CFrance     12
B       7       Russia          BRussia     7
```

Maybe someone can help, how to get this output?

Comment: There is the JOIN operator in Pig. See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html. The key to join on would be the product.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So do I have to do Full Outer Join by product?

Comment: The problem is that in the output pig does not see the schema of price_1, so i dont know how exactly to define the join.
jnd = JOIN t3 BY product FULL, price_1 BY product
does not work, cause in case of price_1 product is not defined.

Comment: 'price_1 = FOREACH group_pr GENERATE CONCAT(group.product, group.country), SUM(t3.price), group.product AS product;' Then do the join on product. By the way, this is all pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks! well im very new in pig, so ask pretty basic questions

Comment: But i think that Join is not the right way, because it will duplicate rows, instead is necessary to get like was shown in the input below (without repetitions)

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join